# How to add filter pipe to a property of an array of object having undefined value

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-pipe

I am working on an Angular 8 project and I have an array of object with the following values:

```
let studentArray = [ {
 Name: 'Anu',
 Mark: 50,
 IsPassed: true
},
{
 Name: 'Raj',
 Mark: 20,
 IsPassed: false
},
{
 Name: 'Tom',
 Mark: 15
}]
```

Here, you can see Raj and Tom are failed students. I need to show only details of the student who are failed. To filter this array, I have added a filter.pipe.ts and the code is given below:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(list: any[], key: string, value: any): any {
    return list.filter(i => i[key] === value);
  }

}
```

Then I added the filter pipe on my HTML page like follows:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of studentArray | filter : 'IsPassed' : false;"> 
....
....
</div>
```

I couldn't able to filter this array using my filter.pipe.ts. Is anything wrong here?

Actually, the 'IsPassed' property for 'Tom' is 'undefined' and it is a nullable property. I need to treat undefined as 'false'. But considering my requirement, I can't able to filter studentArray from .ts file. I need a solution to filter this array from the HTML page itself.

I have added my code to the following 'stackblitz' link:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/filter-pipe-puagzk?file=app%2Fhello.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to evaluate whether you want to compare against true or false first. Then check which entry matches.

```
return list.filter(i => (value) ?  !!(i[key]) : !(i[key]));
```

Comment: Thanks @lynx. But it is not working.  please check this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/filter-pipe-puagzk?file=app%2Fpipes%2Ffilter.pipe.ts

Comment: Sorry, but your stackblitz does not use my code.

Comment: Sorry @Lynx. I mean my code is available on that link. I tried your code. Thanks

Comment: got it. Please try my edited code above. It works with your stackblitz.

Answer (score 0):

you are not checking whether the property exists or not, so correct the return part and see if it works:

```
return list.filter(i => i[key] && i[key] == value);
```

Comment: Thanks @Elys. It is not working. Please check this link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/filter-pipe-puagzk?file=app%2Fpipes%2Ffilter.pipe.ts